# How do I add to calendar without user prompt UWP C#

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

I am creating a Windows10 app, specifically for WindowsPhone.

The app needs to add an appointment to the users calendar. So far I have managed to do this but the user has to authorise each appointment.

Here is the code I have (pulled pretty much straight out of the UWP examples on GitHub):

```
private async void CreateTestCalendarEntry_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string errorMessage = null;
    var appointment = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.Appointment();

    // StartTime
    var date = DateTime.Now;
    var timeZoneOffset = TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now);
    var startTime = new DateTimeOffset(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, date.Hour, date.Minute, date.Second, timeZoneOffset);
    appointment.StartTime = startTime;

    // Subject
    appointment.Subject = "Test Calendar Entry " + date.ToString();

    if (appointment.Subject.Length > 255)
    {
        errorMessage = "The subject cannot be greater than 255 characters.";
    }

    // Location
    appointment.Location = "Japan";

    if (appointment.Location.Length > 32768)
    {
        errorMessage = "The location cannot be greater than 32,768 characters.";
    }

    // Details
    appointment.Details = "Details";

    if (appointment.Details.Length > 1073741823)
    {
        errorMessage = "The details cannot be greater than 1,073,741,823 characters.";
    }

    // Duration
    // All Day
    appointment.AllDay = true;

    // Reminder            
    appointment.Reminder = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);

    //Busy Status            
    appointment.BusyStatus = Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.AppointmentBusyStatus.WorkingElsewhere;

    // Sensitivity            
    appointment.Sensitivity = Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.AppointmentSensitivity.Public;

    var rect = new Rect(new Point(Window.Current.Bounds.Width / 2, Window.Current.Bounds.Height / 2), new Size());
    String appointmentId = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.AppointmentManager.ShowAddAppointmentAsync(appointment, rect, Windows.UI.Popups.Placement.Default);

}
```

Using this code, the await line opens the users calendar and displays the following, where the user can authorise or delete:

[image: User Authorisation for calendar insert]

Hitting the save button, does as expected.

The problem - suppose I have 20 appointments to add to the users calendar, the user isn't going to want to authorise each one. How do I create an appointment without leaving my app and without the user needing to authorise it?

Comment: There is no api for that currently. Suggest it at [uservoice](wpdev.uservoice.com).

Comment: Think about what you are asking. If this was allowed, anyone could create an app that could import 1000's of spam calendar appointments without the user knowing. Even 1 spam appointment would be too much. This is by design and shouldn't be changed imho.

Comment: Users give so many permissions to apps (contact names and numbers, access to location data, notifications, email, media, etc etc) these days that spam calendar entries would be the least of their worries. Besides, users can see what an app has access to before they install it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by writing to your own custom calendar. The required lines of code are these:

```
async private Task CreateCalenderEntry() 
    { 
        // 1. get access to appointmentstore 
        var appointmentStore = await AppointmentManager.RequestStoreAsync(AppointmentStoreAccessType.AppCalendarsReadWrite);

        // 2. get calendar 
        var appCustomApptCalendar = await appointmentStore.CreateAppointmentCalendarAsync("MyCalendar");

        // 3. create new Appointment 
        var appo = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.Appointment();

        // appointment properties 
        appo.AllDay = true; 
        appo.Subject = "Mein Termin";            
        appo.StartTime = DateTime.Now;

        //  4. add 
        await appCustomApptCalendar.SaveAppointmentAsync(appo); 
    }
```

I just tried it on Windows 10 Desktop and it worked. Should work on W10Mobile, too. 
However, it requires that the user shows the custom calendar. I think this should work for you.

I once wrote a blogpost (in German) covering this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dmx/2014/07/24/termine-im-windows-phone-per-api-anlegen-ohne-broker/
It also explains that this even works from background. (to understand the text just use http://www.bing.com/translator if code alone is not sufficient, sorry for the inconvenience).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info - would this mean that the custom calendar would only be available on that device - rather than if you were using the default calendar (outlook for example) which would sync across devices? I'm new to UWP and mobile dev.

Comment: I'd also like to know more about this. I was using Rick's solution above, but syncing from the Windows 10 desktop calendar app with gmail and syncing on all devices.
This is a nice solution to get rid of the annoying pop ups, but accessibility over all devices is key here. If you have any solutions, we'd love to hear them!